# Adding leading zeros to zipcodes that are less than 5 digits in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda

I have a pandas dataframe that has a column of zipcodes and I want to add leading zeros to the zipcodes so they all have five digits.

This is the code I use which correctly identifies the values that are less than 5 digits long but doesn't add leading zeros to make it a length of 5. It also correctly skips the ones that are 5 digits long with an empty cell. The values come in as floats so I convert them to strings.

Here's the code I am using:

```
df_tellall['zipcode'] = df_tellall['zipcode'].astype(str)
df_tellall['cleanzip'] = df_tellall['zipcode'].apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(5)  if len(str(x))<5 else "")
```

But it doesn't add leading zeros.

| zipcode | cleanzip |
| --- | --- |
| 67509 |  |
| 4759 | 4759 |

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a trailing space in zipcode?

Comment: Are you sure `cleanzip` is a string type?

Comment: Why  not copy the "correct" values to `cleanzip` so that you have all the fixed values in one column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
# convert "zipcode" to string (if necessary):
df["zipcode"] = df["zipcode"].astype(str)

# cleanzip will become "" when length >= 5, otherwise fill it with leading zeros:
df["cleanzip"] = np.where(
    df["zipcode"].str.len() < 5, df["zipcode"].str.zfill(5), ""
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  zipcode cleanzip
0   67509         
1    4759    04759
```

Comment: *How* is it not working? It should.

Comment: Are you sure the original numbers were converted from integers and not padded with spaces? Is there a difference between `df["zipcode"].str.len()` and `df["zipcode"].str.strip().str.len()`?

Comment: So it worked...but when the file is sent to a csv output file in excel it strips off the leading zeros again...not sure how to fix that.  Any comments about that would be helpful. Thanks so much!

Comment: @pyphan That's Excel question, see e.g.: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keeping-leading-zeros-and-large-numbers-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7

Comment: Thanks so much everyone! Love SO. I was hoping there would be a way to override it in python - I know how to manually correct it in excel. I'm going to also try an xls export to see if that's the same results.

Comment: @pyphan you might check the latest changes in Excel, I know they were modifying the data import to make it less likely to mangle your data.  Too late for the genetics researchers though, they had to rename a bunch of genes because they looked too much like dates.